# cumulative sum dataframe by date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a pandas dataframe and I need to work out the cumulative sum for every last 20 days.

```
User       Date      A    B  
User1   01/10/2020   1    0 
User1   10/10/2020   0    1
User1   15/10/2020   1    1
User1   21/10/2020   0    0
User2   10/10/2020   0    0
User2   21/10/2020   1    0
User2   03/11/2020   1    0
```

so for every row sum only rows in the last 20 days.

```
User       Date      A    B  
User1   01/10/2020   1    0 
User1   10/10/2020   1    1
User1   15/10/2020   2    2
User1   21/10/2020   1    2
User2   10/10/2020   0    0
User2   21/10/2020   1    0
User2   03/11/2020   2    0
```

i used `cumsum`

```
df.groupby("user").cumsum()
```

but i dont know how to check date and sum cumulative only for last 20 days.

Comment: use rolling sum sample code  `series.rolling(20).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Use rolling with a fixed window:

```
tmp = (
    df.groupby('User')
        .apply(lambda group: group.rolling('20d', on='Date').sum())
)
df[['A_cumsum', 'B_cumsum']] = tmp[['A','B']]
```

Output:

```
    User       Date  A  B  A_cumsum  B_cumsum
0  User1 2020-10-01  1  0       1.0       0.0
1  User1 2020-10-10  0  1       1.0       1.0
2  User1 2020-10-15  1  1       2.0       2.0
3  User1 2020-10-21  0  0       1.0       2.0
4  User2 2020-10-10  0  0       0.0       0.0
5  User2 2020-10-21  1  0       1.0       0.0
6  User2 2020-11-03  1  0       2.0       0.0
```